# Calculating angle of refraction of water in this lab setup?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, refraction, geometric-optics

The setup of the experiment is as drawn in the picture (where the red circle is a rotating disk, the box is a laser and the straight line the laser beam and the semi circle in the middle of the rotating disk is a container with a liquid) and the goal is to find the angle of refraction ($\theta_2$) in the picture. Knowing $\theta_1$ and the distance $d$, how can we find $\theta_2$? (The blue dotted line is the normal to the surface of refra

Answer (score 1):

The setup is such that you get refraction from air to liquid as the light enters the semicircle (via the material of the wall of whatever container you have), but that the ray will not be refracted again when the light leaves the container (assuming things are properly aligned, the angle of incidence of the light internal to the container is normal to the surface). There will be a little bit of focusing of the laser light as it leaves the container... but it shouldn't be deflected.

So you need to look at the simple application of Snell's law: $$\frac{\sin\theta_1}{n_1}=\frac{\sin\theta_2}{n_2}$$

Note that the deflection *on the screen* relative to the straight beam is $\theta_1-\theta_2$.

In your example, with $d=6.6 ~\rm{cm}$, you get an angle $\theta_1-\theta_2=3.8°$, and if $\theta_1=10°$ it follows that $\theta_2=6.2°$. If you ended up with a negative sign, you did "something" wrong. Hard to follow the explanation of your reasoning exactly - see if you can follow mine and spot the difference.

Perhaps you forgot that you had $d$ in units of cm - 6.6 cm = 0.066 m? You didn't specify the units (ALWAYS specify the units) and this may be what tripped you up. I am *assuming* that you meant cm - from the drawing and the magnitude of the numbers, it's the only unit that makes sense.